# LDAP - Getting user's group names fails from IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, ldap

I followed a [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649227.aspx) to implement LDAP authentication on an ASP.NET/C# 4.0 Web Application. While things do seem to work, when I put the website under IIS7, it fails to obtain the group names.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory;

namespace KEWeb
{
    public class LdapAuthentication
    {
        private string _path;
        private string _filterAttribute;
        private string _username;
        private string _password;
        private string _domain;
        private string _domainAndUsername;
        private DirectoryEntry _entry;
        private DirectorySearcher _search;
        private SearchResult _result;

        public LdapAuthentication(string path, string domain, string username, string password)
        {
            _path = path;
            _domain = domain;
            _username = username;
            _password = password;
            _domainAndUsername = _domain + @"\" + _username;
            _entry = new DirectoryEntry(_path, _domainAndUsername, _password);

        }

        public bool IsAuthenticated()
        {
            try
            {
                Object obj = _entry.NativeObject;
                _search = new DirectorySearcher(_entry);
                _search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + _username + ")";
                _search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
                _result = _search.FindOne();
                if (null == _result) { return false; }
                _path = _result.Path;
                _filterAttribute = (String)_result.Properties["cn"][0];
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { throw new Exception("Error authenticating user: " + ex.Message); }
            return true;
        }

        public string GetGroups()
        {
            string r = "";
            try
            {
                Object obj = _entry.NativeObject;
                _search = new DirectorySearcher(_entry);
                _search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + _username + ")";
                _search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
                _result = _search.FindOne();
                if (null != _result)
                {
                    _path = _result.Path;
                    _filterAttribute = (String)_result.Properties["cn"][0];
                    _search = new DirectorySearcher(_path);
                    _search.Filter = "(cn=" + _filterAttribute + ")";
                    _search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");
                    StringBuilder groupNames = new StringBuilder();
                    _result = _search.FindOne();
                    int propertyCount = _result.Properties["memberOf"].Count;
                    String dn;
                    int equalsIndex, commaIndex;
                    for (int propertyCounter = 0; propertyCounter < propertyCount; propertyCounter++)
                    {
                        dn = (String)_result.Properties["memberOf"][propertyCounter];
                        equalsIndex = dn.IndexOf("=", 1);
                        commaIndex = dn.IndexOf(",", 1);
                        if (-1 == equalsIndex) { return null; }
                        groupNames.Append(dn.Substring((equalsIndex + 1), (commaIndex - equalsIndex) - 1));
                        groupNames.Append("|");
                    }
                    r = groupNames.ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { throw new Exception("Error obtaining group names: " + ex.Message); }

            return r;
        }
    }
}
```

When running this in debug from Visual Studio 2010, it works fine. But on IIS7, it gives an error `An operations error occured.` Not sure how to debug this while under IIS, although I'm sure it's possible. If I completely ignore `GetGroups()` and comment that code out, it works, but of course I need these group names.

PS - Yes, the code above is nothing like the original, I tweaked it to re-use some redundant stuff. I did however have this issue before I changed that.

Comment: Is this a directory permissions problem?  In other words: does the user (or machine) that is connecting to the IIS server have permissions to perform the query?  In my scenario, my development box is not a member of the directory.  I would query, and get a DirectoryServicesCOMException on almost any query.

Comment: If that was the case then it would be the other way around, because the one which is working is a standard user and the IIS machine is as a domain admin, but then again IIS runs in session 0. Both machines are a part of the same domain in the same subnet.

Comment: In our environment we have to set the identity of the application pool to a user who has access to the directory.

Comment: I was so sure this was the problem, only after changing this, I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're searching using the wrong item for the groups - you need to use:

```
_search = new DirectorySearcher(_path);
```

in the `GetGroups()` call. The `_path` variable is set by the `IsAuthenticated()` call.

Comment: I'm not understanding what you're trying to say, your line of code above is precisely what I have in my code.

Comment: Wait, it's there twice actually, I see what you're saying now, and the reason I have this twice is so it re-authenticates on the spot when it gets the group names. I had an issue where `GetGroups()` didn't work because `IsAuthenticated()` was never called. Perhaps I just need to re-structure this entire class.

Comment: You're recycling items that should really be used per-function e.g. the `DirectorySearcher` objects, and the duplicate search in the getGroups call did confuse me when I was looking at the code. If your reauthentication in `getGroups` doesn't reset `_path`, then your search with `_path` ends up trying to search with an unauthenticated DirectoryEntry, which triggers an operations error

Comment: Although this unfortunately did not help me locate and fix my problem, it did help me get a better sense of where the problem must be coming from.

Answer (score 1):

You can debug an application under iis, if you attach to the w3wp process. Use the CTRL+Alt+P hotkey to attach to it, or go to Debug menu and choose Attach to Process... and check in the "Show processes in all sessions" checkbox.

Comment: ...assuming IIS and Visual Studio are on the same machine? Because they're not.

Comment: Visual Studio has a Remote Debugger Tool. Its default location is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger. You need to copy the msvsmon.exe to the machine where the iis resides and launch it. Then go to Studio and browse to the remote machine from the Qualifier. After all you should see the w3wp process and attach to it. But the remote machine has to be in the same domain as the machine where the Studio  is running.

Answer (score 0):

This may be way too late to help but I had exactly the same issue.

For me it was the IIS Site had ASP.Net Impersonation and Anonymous both enabled and the Impersonation user was configured to use authenticated user. Since Anonymous was also enabled, this would always fail since Anonymous users do NOT have access to AD.

Changed ASP.Net Impersonation to use a valid AD account and voila!

John

PS. I was working from the same tutorial as you as well. :)